# ¿como validar inputs vacios en jasascript vanilla?

Tags: javascript

tengo varios input de clase rut y otro nombre respectivamente, al momento de escribir si hay texto vacio que me mande una validacion este campo esta vacio y se coloque el foco en ese input
el evento que ocupo es el onkeyup en los insput de dichas clases pero no me resulta
solo debe ser cuando se ha dejado de escribir

```js
function validar(){
    var validado = true;
    elementos = document.querySelectorAll(".rut");
    for(i=0;i<elementos.length;i++){
      if(elementos[i].value == "" || elementos[i].value == null){
      validado = false
      }
    }
    if(validado){
    document.querySelector("#guardardatos").disabled = false;
    
    }else{
       document.querySelector("#guardardatos").disabled = true;

    alert("Hay campos vacios")   
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar" disabled />


<input type="number" class="rut"  onkeyup="validar()" min="0"></td>
<input type="number" class="rut"  onkeyup="validar()" min="0"></td>
<input type="number" class="rut"  onkeyup="validar()" min="0"></td>
<input type="number" class="rut"  onkeyup="validar()" min="0"></td>
```

Comment: Dices que tienes varios elementos de la clase `rut` y luego tu HTML no tiene uno solo de esa clase, ni el javascript hace referencia a ellos. Quizás preparando el ejemplo la descripción se quedó en una etapa y el código en otra. Por favor, corrige uno u otro para que se pueda entender bien la pregunta.

Comment: Pero ya está validando... ¿Cuál es tu resultado esperado?, ¿Cuál es el error?...

Comment: necesito que sea al dejar de escribir

Comment: ¿Pero eso no ocurre?... en todo caso prueba con `onblur` en vez de `onkeyup`.

Comment: Hola Felipe, tal vez yo no esté entendiendo, pero... quieres comprobar si al dejar de escribir el campo está vacío?, o estoy muy dormido, o jamás va a estar vacío después de escribir.